# Find the norm of this operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, convolution

Consider the operator $A:\mathcal L_{2,w}(\mathbb R)\to\mathcal L_{2,w}(\mathbb R)$, which maps from the weighted $\mathcal L_2$-type space to itself. The operator acts in the following way:
$$(Af)(t)=(\chi_{[0,\infty)}*f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tf(s)ds,$$
and can be thought of as a convolution operator where one of the convolved functions is fixed as the indicator function on $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$.
The norm on this space is an extension of the usual $\mathcal L_2$-norm and is given by
$$\|f\|_{\mathcal L_{2,w}}=\left(\int_{\mathbb R}|f(t)|^2e^{-2wt}\text{d}t\right),$$ where $w\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ is a fixed parameter.

I want to **find the operator norm** of $A$. Using Young's inequality I have been able to show that $\|A\|\le\|\chi_{[0,\infty)}\|_{\mathcal L_{1,w}}=\frac{1}{|w|}$, but am not sure on showing the other direction. I have found this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474872/compute-operator-norm-of-convolution-with-gaussian) to be quite similar to mine, and am wondering if there is an obvious choice of $f\in\mathcal L_{2,w}$ to make use of here. On the other hand, I wonder if I should make use of an approximate identity or similar.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the $\mathcal L_1$-norm of $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$ is $1/|w|$?

Comment: Remember that this is the *weighted* $\mathcal L_{1,w}$-type norm. We have: $\|\chi_{[0,\infty)}\|_{\mathcal L_{1,w}}=\int_\mathbb R|\chi_{[0,\infty)}(t)|e^{-wt}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-wt}dt=\left[\frac{-1}{|w|}e^{-wt}\right]_0^\infty=\frac{1}{|w|}$.

Comment: Ahh, ok.. I somehow misread it and thought there's also an $i$ in the exponent.